# Have more than one custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I'm building a WordPress theme and want to add custom post types. I've look online but can't seem to find an answer.

Now I have this code in the functions.php

```php
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_tutorial' );

function register_cpt_tutorial() {

$labels = array( 
    'name' => _x( 'Tutorials', 'tutorial' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
    'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'tutorial' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
    'new_item' => _x( 'New Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
    'view_item' => _x( 'View Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Search Tutorials', 'tutorial' ),
    'not_found' => _x( 'No tutorials found', 'tutorial' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No tutorials found in Trash', 'tutorial' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Tutorial:', 'tutorial' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'Tutorials', 'tutorial' ),
);

$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'description' => 'Tutorials description will be here',
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,

    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post'
);

register_post_type( 'tutorial', $args );
}
```

If I copy and past this code and change the 'tutorials' to 'video' it does not make a second post type. Can someone please help me?

Comment: change your labels too

Comment: Sorry @wordpresser can you explain? If I change all of the tutorial, tutorials ect... to video, videos it does not work? What are the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the WP plugin Custom Post Type UI

http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

but if you want to use the code try this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_cpt_tutorial' );

function register_cpt_tutorial() {

$labels = array( 
    'name' => _x( 'Tutorials', 'tutorial' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
    'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'tutorial' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
    'new_item' => _x( 'New Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
    'view_item' => _x( 'View Tutorial', 'tutorial' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Search Tutorials', 'tutorial' ),
    'not_found' => _x( 'No tutorials found', 'tutorial' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No tutorials found in Trash', 'tutorial' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent Tutorial:', 'tutorial' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'Tutorials', 'tutorial' ),
);

$args = array( 
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'description' => 'Tutorials description will be here',
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,

    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post'
);
// ----- Second post type
$labels2 = array( 
    'name' => _x( 'video', 'video' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'video', 'video' ),
    'add_new' => _x( 'Add New', 'video' ),
    'add_new_item' => _x( 'Add New video', 'video' ),
    'edit_item' => _x( 'Edit video', 'video' ),
    'new_item' => _x( 'New video', 'video' ),
    'view_item' => _x( 'View video', 'video' ),
    'search_items' => _x( 'Search video', 'video' ),
    'not_found' => _x( 'No video found', 'video' ),
    'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'No video found in Trash', 'video' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent video:', 'tutorial' ),
    'menu_name' => _x( 'video', 'video' ),
);

$args2 = array( 
    'labels' => $labels2,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'description' => 'Tutorials description will be here',
    'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'menu_position' => 20,

    'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'has_archive' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'can_export' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post'
);

register_post_type( 'tutorial', $args );
register_post_type( 'video', $args2 );
}
```

Note the change of $args - $args2 and $labels - $labels2